# React pass function to dynamic created child with additional parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, currying

I want to dynamically create child components, receiving an onClick event from their parent/grandparent component in React. During the creation I want to add a parameter to the onClick-event. Basically the desired flow is:

- When rendering parent component
- Pass the reference to the desired function to the creation of the dynamic component
- In process of creating the dynamic component I want to add a parameter, defined by the creator
- the onClick event in the child should call the onClick function in the parent using the parameter it got from the creator of the dynamic component

For the code: this is the dynamic component creator and the parent

```
  import React from 'react';

  // This is the creator of my dynamic components
  // It currently sets this.props.name as parameter for the parent function

  class CreateComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
      return(
        <div className="childBox">
           // this.props.component is a react component of type ImageBox (see next code block)
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.component, {
            open: this.props.open(this.props.name),
            close: this.props.close,
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  // This is the parent component, using the creator and some state to open/close different components
  export class DynamicContentGrid extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { activeComponent: '' };
    }

    close() {
      this.setState({ activeComponent: '' });
    }

    open(component) {
      this.setState({ activeComponent: component })
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.props.children);
      return(
        <div className={css(styles.grid)}>
          <div className={css(styles.boxUpperLeft, styles.box)}>
            <CreateComponent
              component={this.props.children['upperLeft']}
              name='upperLeft'
              open={() => (name) => this.open(name)}
              close={() => this.close()}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }


  export default DynamicContentGrid;
```

And here comes the very basic child component using this.props.close without parameters (they should be set in the creator):

```
import React from 'react';
export class ImageBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {title, link, img} = this.props.content.front;
    return(
          <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <h2 onClick={this.props.open}>{link}</h2>
            <img src={img} />
          </div>
     )
  }
}

export default ImageBox;
```

**What works**

The dynamic rendering of child components works fine.

**Where it breaks**

As you can see, the magic happens in `open={() => (name) => this.open(name)}`. What I want is: pass this.open to the creator, set open(name) as parameter and pass on the open function to the child.

Everything works fine, if I said the "name" parameter directly in the parent, but for several reasons I do not want to do this. So I need some kind of currying but I can't figure out, what is wrong. The parameter "name" is not properly set in the creator at the moment.

Comment: Why not add an delegate funciton in 'this'?

Comment: Can you explain this statement/give an example?

Comment: not sure if anyone's mentioned this before, but this link might help you:
https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CreateComponent set `open: () => this.props.open(this.props.name)`.

Also, remove `() => (name) => this.open(name)` and replace with `this.open` and put `this.open = this.open.bind(this);` into the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Moritz. But it does not work: I get a "setState is not a function" error. I think using () => in CreateComponent binds the context of open to CreateComponent's context while I need the parent's context.

Comment: Edited my answer. Either bind `this.open` in your constructor or rewrite `this.open` into an arrow function. Arrow functions as class properties however, are in proposal stage.